# multiplication table formatting issue

Tags: java, multiplication

Currently when I run my code it displays the  basic multiplication vertically.

```
1
2
2
4
```

How would I get it to display in table format like horizontally and vertically to form a table? Assuming that `i` and `j` are how big you want the table to be.

```
123
246
369
```

#### Code

```
for(int i=1; i<=2; i++){
    for (int j=1; j <= 2; j++){
        //int multiplier =1;
        int answer = i*j;
        //multiplier++;  
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simpler method, you can use 'System.out.print()' (only works for same length results):

```
for(int i=1; i<=2; i++){
    for (int j=1; j <= 2; j++){
        //int multiplier =1;
        int answer = i*j;
        //multiplier++;  
        System.out.print(answer+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Otherwise, you can use 'System.out.format()':

```
for(int i=1; i<=10; i++){
    for (int j=1; j <= 10; j++){
        //int multiplier =1;
        int answer = i*j;
        //multiplier++;  
        System.out.format("%5s", answer);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

More information about 'System.out.format()':
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html